# Tkinter & Threads - Exception: out of stack space (infinite loop?)

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, tkinter, tk-toolkit

We implemented a distributed chat, which is using a Tkinter GUI. As I updated my system to Fedora18 Im getting exceptions when calling a Tkinter event, almost the same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444459/tkinter-event-generate-throws-exception-infinite-loop):

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in bootstrap_inner self.run()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run self.target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/hachat/peer.py", line 156, in startRecvLoop
self.processMessage(msg, addr)
File "/hachat/peer.py", line 222, in processMessage
self.gui.receive(msg) 
File "/hachat/gui.py", line 74, in receive
self.textfenster.insert(END,msg.name+": "+msg.text+'\n')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2986, in insert
self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
TclError: out of stack space (infinite loop?)
```

Here is a snipped out of the gui-class:

```
import Tkinter
import ScrolledText
import tkMessageBox
import tkSimpleDialog
import threading 

class gui(object):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()             
        self.textfenster = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(self.fpopup,width=90,height=24,background='white')
        self.textfenster.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=Tkinter.YES)

    def run(self):
        self.guiRunThread = threading.Thread(target=self.root.mainloop())
        self.guiRunThread.daemon = True
        self.guiRunThread.start()

    def receive(self,msg):
        self.textfenster.insert(Tkinter.END,msg.name+": "+msg.text+'\n')
        self.textfenster.see(Tkinter.END)
```

The Exception appears only on my system, the reason seems to be that tk was not compiled with support for threads. I have to get rid of this Exeption - as the program is distributed it needs to run on different systems. So Im asking for how to get rid of this exception as well as an hint to get tk for supporting threads. 
Im using Python version is 2.7.3, Tcl/Tk version 8.5. `import Tkinter; Tkinter.Tk().tk.eval("puts $tcl_platform(threaded)")` is giving back a Exception as well.

Comment: If you're asking for a change to Tkinter, this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: No, Im not asking for a change to tkinter itself. Only how to get this to work w/o getting the exception and how to get tk to enable threading.

Comment: @wedel you cannot call `gui.receive` from another thread, no matter if you compile everything with thread support or not. The other question is calling `event_generate`, which is quite different. Change your code to use Python's `Queue` for communicating between threads.

Comment: @mmgp: You're right! `gui.receive` is not called from another thread, but from outside the gui-thread.

Comment: @wedel I guess I didn't understand what you just said. What is the difference between "calling it from another thread" and "calling from outside the gui-thread" ?

Comment: @mmgp `gui.receive` is called from another method outside of the the `gui.mainloop`-thread. this works! only on my system the exception is thrown.

Comment: @wedel that is exactly I'm telling you to /NOT/ do.

Comment: Keep all the GUI code in one thread. Really. Have as many other worker threads as you want, but GUI toolkits are written to be single-threaded usually (because they're complex enough even with that simplification, thankyouverymuch!) so be nice and keep your actual GUI code in one thread.

Comment: @DonalFellows Correct me if Im wrong. But the thread with the `target=self.root.mainloop()` as shown above is one thread. The method `gui.receive`  just calls `Tkinter.insert` and is not a part of this thread. It really works on all other systems!

Comment: Internally, Tkinter ought to be pushing everything through the one underlying OS thread anyway (since that's how Tk works, in common with quite a few other GUI toolkits; multithreaded GUI toolkits have been tried and found stupendously confusing to code with). Does it actually do it? I don't know, to be honest! Tkinter's pretty complicated internally; I don't recall seeing any thread handling but it might be in there. I still wouldn't code with it that way though…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with Queues to communicate with Tk. See [Mutli-threading python with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379106/mutli-threading-python-with-tkinter/14381671#14381671) for an example!

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText
from threading import Thread

scrolled = None

def start():
    global scrolled
    root = Tk()
    scrolled = ScrolledText(root)
    scrolled.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    return root

Thread(target=start().mainloop).start()

print scrolled.get(0.0, END)
```