# Two classes having references to each other

Tags: python, tkinter, server, reference, structure

I'm working on an asynchronous TCP server.

All is going well, and I'm learning a lot from it, but I have a question related to the structure.

This is how the structure looks:

[image: Global overview]

The Server object is an asynchronous TCP server running in its own thread.
It communicates with the GUI Controller object via thread-safe queue's.

On the main thread we've got the GUI Controller , the tkinter mainloop and the actual Tkinter GUI class.

here is some code to make it more clear:

```
clientlist = []
#queue's for communicating with server thread
buffer = queue.Queue()
buffer2 = queue.Queue()

root = Tk()
#GUI controller
controller = Controller(buffer,buffer2,clientlist,root)
#Make Tkinter GUI and give a reference to the controller
top = MainWindow(controller, root)
#Giving Tkinter GUI reference to the controller
controller.set_top(top)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_server, args=(buffer,buffer2))
t1.start()

controller.check_connections()


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
try:
    while controller.run:
        root.mainloop()
    print("[i] Joining server thread.")
    t1.join()
```

I have a hard time finding a nice way to make the Tkinter GUI communicate with the GUI controller. The idea I had here to give a reference to each others class is not working:

If I give the *MainWindow* a reference to *Controller*, I need to save it to a variable in the constructor of *MainWindow*. Then I need to update that variable each loop which is very demanding.

How can I give a reference the correct way, or is there a better way to let these two classes communicate?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Set a placeholder for Window object in `Controller.__init__` and create a register function which can reassign it when called.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The Window object needs to know the Controller object as well. So I could apply the same technique there. But then I would still need to call the register function each time the object or its properties change right? Or is there a way to give it an actual reference that points to the object?

Comment: Relevant: [Mutli-threading with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381671/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl I  already use the queue's for communicating between multiple threads.The question was about two objects in the same thread. I did manage to get it working though, I found that I forgot a few `self.` 's. So I was giving a reference the correct way. But I was sometimes writing to the object in the global scope, instead of the actual reference (both classes were in the same _.py_ file) Thanks for your help both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this when moving both the Tkinter GUI class and the controller class to their own `.py` file instead of having both in the same file.

I found that I forgot some `self.`'s so the controller would try to acces the GUI object defined in the global scope instead of the reference I gave. After placing those `self.`'s all is working as I expected!

So for other people:
**If you want to give two objects a reference to each other**:

1. Set a placeholder for the other object in each constructor. (thanks @Dashadower)
2. Give each class a method to reassign that placeholder with the actual reference 
                                (Give the object as an argument)
3. Dont forget to call the *objects reference* of the other *object*. (USE `self.`)