# Tkinter Running Task In Background

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm making an app where you can message other people (just for learning & testing purposes) and I would like to have a window open with a listener running in the background waiting for someone to type something into a google spreadsheet (using the same program to input to a spreadsheet & listen and display that message) and I a cannot figure out how to do that (threading? multiprocessing?). Here's my code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
#basic import below
import os
import time
from time import gmtime, strftime
import sys
from queue import Queue
import getpass
import threading
from tkinter import *
import threading
#setup stuff

version = '1.0'
written = '3/5/2019'

currentUser = getpass.getuser()
print("Currrent User = " + currentUser)
jsonDict = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "glossy-aloe-233621",
  "private_key_id": "c9f3e566e7482867e941bcd7129e2bbf87cf7429",
  "private_key": PRIVATEKEYSTUFF,
  "client_email": EMAIL STUFF,
  "client_id": "116858167893987826316",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/pymessengerclient%40glossy-aloe-233621.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}


scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(jsonDict, scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
#get
wks = gc.open('PyMessenger').sheet1

#------------------------------------------------------------
#STUFF TO LOOK AT BELOW





def sendMessage(self, message):
  currentTime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
  wks.append_row([str(currentUser), str(message), str(currentTime)])


def listener(self):
  i = 0
  lastM = ""
  while(True):
    colVals = wks.col_values(2)
    prevU = colVals[-1]
    if prevU != "Message":
      if lastM != prevU:
        cell = wks.find(prevU)
        row = cell.row
        vallist = wks.row_values(row)
        sent = vallist[0] + ": " + vallist[1] + " - " + vallist[2]
        print(vallist[0] + ": " + vallist[1] + " - " + vallist[2])
        txt.insert(0.0, sent)
        lastM = prevU
      else:
        pass
    time.sleep(2)



def createMessage(self):
  messageRaw = ent.get()
  self.sendMessage(messageRaw)

#---------------------------------------------
root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x300")
root.title("PyMessenger")

l1 = Label(root, text="Message:")

ent = Entry(root)

send = Button(root, text="Send", command=createMessage)

l1.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
ent.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

send.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

txt = Text(root, width=45, height=15, wrap=WORD)
txt.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky=W)




#HERE RUN WINDOW & LISTEN TASK IN BACKGROUND
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Relevant: [Mutli-threading with Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381671/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution!**

Create another function (I called it ThreadTask()) and inside put `a = threading.Thread(name='background', target=listener)
  a.start()` and it below before 'root.mainloop()' do 'root.after(100, threadtask)' and that will run the listener and stop freezing by putting it in another thread!