# Tkinter intvar causing process to live on

Tags: python, tkinter, process

I realize there are many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110923/close-a-tkinter-window) of how to properly close a Tkinter GUI by calling the root.destroy() function. They work with my setup except I've determined that including a variable of type tkinter.intvar causes the gui process to live on even after I close the window. Here's a working example:

```
import mtTkinter as Tkinter #special threadsafe version of Tkinter module, required for message windows. You can use regular Tkinter if needed 

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("KillmePlz")

nexusvar = Tkinter.IntVar()

def ClosebyX():
    root.destroy()

closebutton = Tkinter.Button(root,text='Quit',command=ClosebyX)
closebutton.pack()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', ClosebyX)
root.mainloop()
```

On my machine if I remove the creation of "nexusvar", the Tkinter.IntVar, when I close the GUI the process also stops. If this variable is included as shown above, I see the process linger after the gui is closed. I don't think mtTkinter makes any difference.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Windows 7 64 bit, Python 2.7.12

UPDATE 9/20/16:
mtTkinter is the source of this problem. The solution below is for regular Tkinter module use. For solving this problem using mtTkinter see the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073463/mttkinter-doesnt-terminate-threads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nexusvar` isn't a child of `root`, so when you destroy `root` it doesn't know to destroy `nexusvar` as well - the two things are separate. You can set an `IntVar` to have `root` as a parent by supplying `root` to the constructor. `nexusvar` should then be able to destroy itself when `root` dies.

Comment: I tried nexusvar = Tkinter.IntVar(master=root) and I still observe the same issue. Is that what you meant when you say make root the parent?

Comment: I can confirm the issue persists whether in IDLE shell or from an executable (py2exe)

Comment: It looks my use of mtTkinter module is the culprit. When I apply your solution with the regular Tkinter module there are no issues. mtTkinter needs to address this