# Daemon thread not exiting despite main program finishing

Tags: python, multithreading

I've already referred to this thread, but it seems to be outdated
and there doesn't seem to be a clean explanation

[Python daemon thread does not exit when parent thread exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843916/python-daemon-thread-does-not-exit-when-parent-thread-exits)

I'm running python 3.6 and trying to run the script from either IDLE or Spyder IDE.

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import time

total = 4

def creates_items():
    global total
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(2)
        print('added item')
        total += 1
    print('creation is done')


def creates_items_2():
    global total
    for i in range(7):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('added item')
        total += 1
    print('creation is done')


def limits_items():

    #print('finished sleeping')

    global total
    while True:
        if total > 5:

            print ('overload')
            total -= 3
            print('subtracted 3')
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            print('waiting')


limitor = threading.Thread(target = limits_items, daemon = True)
creator1 = threading.Thread(target  = creates_items)
creator2 = threading.Thread(target = creates_items_2)


print(limitor.isDaemon())


creator1.start()
creator2.start()
limitor.start()


creator1.join()
creator2.join()

print('our ending value of total is' , total)
```

limitor thread doesn't seem to be ending despite being a daemon thread.

Is this a way to get this working from IDLE or Spyder?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't end?

Comment: The print statement ('waiting') continues to be outputted after main thread ends.  This is when using a Python console such as IDLE or Spyder (not the command prompt)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem and solved it by using multiprocessing instead of threading:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

def daemon_thread():
    for _ in range(10):
        sleep(1)
        print("Daemon")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    sub_process = Process(target = daemon_thread, daemon = True)
    sub_process.start()

    print("Exiting Main")
```

I haven't yet really understood why I need the call to freeze_support() but it makes the code work.

Comment: Thanks.  However, multiprocessing takes up a lot more resources.