# Python: Unable to open and write to file from thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create/open and write to a file from thread.

```
from threading import Thread


CONNECTION_PORT = 9191

def testl():
    file = open("testfile.txt","w") 
    file.write("Hello World") 
    file.write("This is our new text file") 
    file.write("and this is another line.") 
    file.write("Why? Because we can.") 

    file.close() 

def test():
    t = Thread(target=testl)
    # t.daemon = True
    t.start()


test()
```

The problem is that when I un-comment 2nd line (t.daemon = True) of the test function it stops working. Is there any way to make it work in the daemon thread mode ??

I can't find any solution on internet or even related to this. I know it is not the best way for file operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python daemon thread does not exit when parent thread exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843916/python-daemon-thread-does-not-exit-when-parent-thread-exits)

Answer (score 0):

A daemon thread means that python need not wait for the thread to complete before the program exits.
So, what happens is:

- `test()` starts the thread
- `test()` ends, and the thread containing `test()` (the main thread probably) ends
- There are no non-daemon threads
- python exits.

I don't really think you want the thread to be a daemon thread.
If you do, you should have some non-daemon thread call `t.join()` so that you wait for that thread to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help to understand it better, why your daemon thread ends with out finishing his job.

- Daemon Threads: Daemon threads are designed **to run alongside the main thread**. They are suitable for background tasks or services that can operate independently. When the main thread exits, **daemon threads are abruptly terminated**. Use them for non-critical, background tasks that should not keep the program running after the main work is done.
- Non-Daemon Threads: Non-daemon threads are considered part of the main program's work. **The program will wait for them to finish** before exiting. Use non-daemon threads for tasks that must complete before the program can cleanly exit.