# Write something in a file by a Daemon Thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to write something in a file by a daemon thread. The problem is that the file is being created but it is empty. Is it possible to write in a file by a daemon thread?

The reason of using daemon thread is because my main program will terminate first as compared to my thread. So in order to keep that thread running even after the execution of the program daemon is used.

Below is the code:

```
import threading

def hlp():
    with open("/path/to/y.txt",mode="w") as f:
        f.write("Hello")

def test():
    thr=threading.Thread(target=hlp)
    thr.daemon=True
    thr.start()

test()
```

Comment: You dont need `f.close()` when you are using `with`

Comment: Thank you for that. What about daemon thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the use of join() in python threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a daemon thread might not be what you want since a daemon thread won't wait for the thread to complete before the program exits.

If you still want to use a daemon you should use `.join()` so that you wait for that thread to finish.

Example:

```
import threading

def hlp():
    with open("/path/to/y.txt",mode="w") as f:
        f.write("Hello")

def test():
    thr=threading.Thread(target=hlp)
    thr.daemon=True
    thr.start()
    thr.join()

test()
```

Comment: The only other way (if you want to main thread to die off) is to use multiprocessing.

Comment: Use another process to handle it.

Comment: My problem is that my main program will finish it's execution before the thread finishes it's execution. Does multiprocessing provide the execution of the process even after the main program's execution is over? This was my main reason of using daemon thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624850/launch-a-completely-independent-process

Comment: There's some information there in regards to what you might want to do.

Answer (score 2):

[Coming from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading), It looks like you need to `join` the thread after you start it when you're playing with a daemon thread:

In other words:

> with `join` - interpreter will wait until your process get **completed** or
>   **terminated**, in this case file being **written**

```
import threading
def hlp():
    with open("C:\\Users\\munir.khan\\PycharmProjects\\opencv-basics2019-03-22_14-49-26\\y.txt",mode="a+") as f:
        f.write("Hello")

def test():
    thr=threading.Thread(target=hlp)
    thr.daemon=True
    thr.start()
    thr.join()

test()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Hello
```

**EDIT**:

If you do not want to use `join`, you may set `thr.daemon=False`, but I don't like it since, it says here that [Setting `thread.daemon = True` allows the main program to exit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330111/python-thread-daemon-property)

```
import threading
def hlp():
    with open("C:\\Users\\munir.khan\\PycharmProjects\\opencv-basics2019-03-22_14-49-26\\y.txt",mode="a+") as f:
        f.write("Hello")

def test():
    thr=threading.Thread(target=hlp)
    thr.daemon=False
    thr.start()

test()
```

Comment: join makes the main program wait till the execution of the thread is done. I don't want that. I want the program to run as it and terminate if it wants to but the thread should still keep running till it finishes its work and not make main thread wait.

Comment: @Amay but if you must insist, use `thr.daemon=False` but I won't recommend it.

Comment: Daemon's thread purpose is to run the thread even after the execution of the main program. So I think daemon thread maybe the right way.

Comment: Yeah now I am able to find the text in the file. The thread is able to append but not write? But you have removed the daemon thread, which I wanted to use for my case

Comment: In the example using `thr.daemon=False`, (which you can omit, `False` is the ["default" as inherited from the main thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon), after all), `join()` _is_ called implicitly when [`threading._shutdown`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/threading.py#L1279-L1282) is executed. That function is called during interpreter shutdown in [`wait_for_thread_shutdown`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pylifecycle.c#L2164). Non-daemonic threads will be joined, either explicitly or implicitly.