# Bug when using typing & daemon threads

Tags: python, multithreading

When I run this code on Python 3.11 it runs fine, but if I import `typing_minimal` (or `typing`) in `reader.py` I get this error:

```
Fatal Python error: _enter_buffered_busy: could not acquire lock for <_io.BufferedReader name='<stdin>'> at interpreter shutdown, possibly due to daemon threads
Python runtime state: finalizing (tstate=0x00007fff13ab6960)

Current thread 0x00003944 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

main.py:

```py
import reader
from typing_minimal import Generic, TypeVar

VALUE = TypeVar("VALUE")


class BaseClass(Generic[VALUE]):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class SubClass(BaseClass[VALUE]):
    pass


reader.thread.start()
```

reader.py:

```py
from sys import stdin
from threading import Thread

# BUG: I get an error when I uncomment this import:
# import typing_minimal


thread = Thread(target=lambda: stdin.buffer.read(), daemon=True)
```

typing_minimal.py:

```py
from functools import lru_cache, wraps


def _tp_cache(func):
    cached = lru_cache()(func)

    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwds):
        return cached(*args, **kwds)

    return inner


class TypeVar:
    def __init__(self, _):
        pass


class _GenericAlias:
    def __init__(self, origin):
        self.origin = origin

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, _GenericAlias):
            return self.origin is other.origin

        return NotImplemented

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.origin)

    def __mro_entries__(self, _):
        return (self.origin,)


class Generic:
    @_tp_cache
    def __class_getitem__(cls, *_):
        return _GenericAlias(cls)
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I'm very confused.

*Note: while this code produces the same error, this question is about why importing `typing_minimal` in `reader.py` breaks things:*

```py
from sys import stdin
from threading import Thread


Thread(target=stdin.buffer.read, daemon=True).start()
```

Comment: "possibly due to daemon threads" - the main thread can shut down [without terminating the daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330111/meaning-of-daemon-property-on-python-threads). I think in this case the main thread tries to shut down, but it can't close `stdin` because it's used by the daemon thread. I don't think it's related to `SubClass` being defined or not.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can duplicate this in Python 3.10 on Linux.  That's very, very weird.  `typing` has already been imported.

Comment: Same on Python 3.12, macOS. (And it's not about `Any`, simply importing `typing` is sufficient.)

Comment: Try to import typing_minimal at different points in your code to see if it affects the error. This might help identify if the issue is related to import timing.

Comment: @jepozdemir, it still crashes when I import it at the top or bottom.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with typing.

If you remove everything related to typing_minimal from your code and try to import another non-trivial sized module, and you'll get basically the same error.

You could replicate the same error in just one file:

```
# main.py
import sys
from threading import Thread

def read():
    sys.stdin.buffer.read()

Thread(target=read, daemon=True).start()
```

This is basically [bpo-42717](https://bugs.python.org/issue42717) aka [#86883](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86883) on GitHub.

What's happening here seems to be that the daemon thread is trying to use stdin and blocking after the main thread has decided to shutdown. This used to cause the interpreter to deadlock during shutdown, so in [bpo-23309](https://bugs.python.org/issue23309), the fatal error you are seeing is added to intentionally crash Python to break that deadlock.

The reason your code crashes or not by just by the presence of typing is a race condition. When you remove import typing (or import any other module), that alters the timing of when the daemon thread reads from sys.stdin just enough to not trigger the issue.

Comment: It doesn't crash if you import `stdin` from `sys`, which also doesn't make sense. `typing_minimal` seems to somehow break things with `lru_cache`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with lru_cache or typing/minimal. Try replacing your `import typing` in reader.py with `import subprocess` or `asyncio` or `logging`. They all crash exactly the same way.

Comment: I suspect the reason why importing some modules triggers the crash and others don't is likely just because importing certain things causes reference cycles that possibly delays the garbage collection or it affects the timing. Running your code in a virtualenv changes what modules caused a crashed and the ones that don't, which is further evidence that this is race condition/timing related.

Comment: It doesn't crash when I import these, are you using `from sys import stdin`?

Comment: I was using exactly your code with the above, changed only the import line. Python 3.12, Mac, no virtualenv. Activating virtualenv causes some modules not to crash, for some reason, which led me to suspect it might be due to some import orders causing references cycles that may affect whether or not the interpreter crashes.

Answer (score -2):

in main.py change

```py
class SubClass(BaseClass[None]):
```

to

```py
class SubClass(BaseClass):
```

and things seem to work.  this seems to be some sort of race condition, but without an explanation of why you need this illegal code in main.py, I think it's best to address the trigger of this race condition then to explain the underlying mechanism.

Comment: I've made the subclass generic too, the bug also works in that case.

Comment: Note that this is a minimal reproducable example, which doesn't seem to do anything useful.