# setDaemon() method of threading.Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am a newbie in python programming, what I understand is that a process can be a daemon, but a thread in a daemon mode, I couldn't understand the usecase of this, I would request the python gurus to help me in understanding this.

Comment: The best answer to this is http://stackoverflow.com/a/190017/260122 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Daemon Threads Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation)

Comment: hue: The `threading` documentation says not to use the old [`setDaemon()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.setDaemon) method (although it doesn't say it use is deprecated).

Comment: It is not old, it has been added as an option when you create the thread as an argument so now you haven't have to use the setter. `class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)`

Comment: @martineau now it is deprecated (as of 2023): "DeprecationWarning: setDaemon() is deprecated, set the daemon attribute instead"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here is some basic code using threading:

```
import Queue
import threading

def basic_worker(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        # do_work(item)
        print(item)
        queue.task_done()
def basic():
    # http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    for i in range(3):
         t = threading.Thread(target=basic_worker,args=(queue,))
         t.daemon = True
         t.start()
    for item in range(4):
        queue.put(item)
    queue.join()       # block until all tasks are done
    print('got here')

basic()
```

When you run it, you get

```
% test.py
0
1
2
3
got here
```

Now comment out the line:

```
         t.daemon = True
```

Run it again, and you'll see that the script prints the same result, but hangs.
The main thread ends (note that `got here` was printed), but the second thread never finishes.

In contrast, when `t.daemon` is set to `True`, the thread `t` is terminated when the main thread ends.

Note that "daemon threads" has little to do with [daemon processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29).

Comment: Should that be t.SetDaemon(True) ?

Comment: @GreenAsJade: [t.setDaemon(True)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.setDaemon) is part of the old API. Nowadays, [t.daemon = True](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) is the recommended way to make `t` a daemon thread.

Comment: But why is it called "daemon threads" when it "has little to do with [daemon processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29)."

Answer (score 16):

It looks like people intend to use Queue to explain threading, but I think there should be a much simpler way, by using `time.sleep()`, to demo a daemon thread.

Create daemon thread by setting the `daemon` parameter (default as None):

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def worker():
    time.sleep(3)
    print('daemon done')

thread = Thread(target=worker, daemon=True)
thread.start()

print('main done')
```

Output:

```
main done

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Remove the daemon argument, like:

```
thread = Thread(target=worker)
```

Re-run and see the output:

```
main done
daemon done

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here we already see the difference of a daemon thread:

> The entire Python program can exit if only daemon thread is left.

---

`isDaemon()` and `setDaemon()` are old getter/setter API. Using constructor argument, as above, or `daemon` property is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

##### In simple words...

#### What is a Daemon thread?

- **daemon threads** can *shut down any time* in between their flow ***whereas*** **non-daemon** (i.e. user threads) *execute completely*.
- **daemon threads** run *intermittently in the background* as long as other **non-daemon threads** are running.
- When all of the **non-daemon threads** are complete, **daemon threads**  terminate automatically *(no matter whether they got fully executed or not)*.
- **daemon threads** are *service providers* for **user threads** running in the same process.
- *python does not care* about **daemon threads** to complete when in **running state**, NOT EVEN the finally block **but** python **does give** preference to **non-daemon threads** that are created by us.
- **daemon threads** act as services in operating systems.
- **python** stops the **daemon threads** when all **user threads** (in contrast to the **daemon threads**) are terminated. Hence **daemon threads** can be used to implement, for example, a monitoring functionality as the thread is stopped by the **python** as soon as all **user threads** have stopped.

#### In a nutshell

If you do something like this

```
thread = Thread(target=worker_method, daemon=True)
```

there is ***NO guarantee*** that `worker_method` will get executed completely.

#### Where does this behaviour be useful?

Consider two threads `t1` *(parent thread)* and `t2` *(child thread)*. Let `t2` be **daemon**. Now, you want to analyze the working of `t1` while it is in running state; you can write the code to do this in `t2`.

Reference:

- [StackOverflow - What is a daemon thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31603321/10204932)
- [GeeksForGeeks - Python daemon threads](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-daemon-threads/)
- [TutotrialsPoint - Concurrency in Python - Threads](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/concurrency_in_python/concurrency_in_python_threads.htm)
- [Official Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon)

Answer (score 2):

Module Queue has been renamed queue starting with Python3 to better reflect the fact that there are several queue classes (lifo, fifo, priority) in the module.
so please make the changes while using this example

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted @unutbu's answer for python 3. Make sure that you run this script from the command line and not some interactive environment like jupyter notebook.

```py
import queue
import threading


def basic_worker(q):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        # do_work(item)
        print(item)
        q.task_done()


def basic():    
    q = queue.Queue()
    for item in range(4):
        q.put(item)    

    for i in range(3):
         t = threading.Thread(target=basic_worker,args=(q,))
         t.daemon = True
         t.start()

    q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
    print('got here')

basic()
```

So when you comment out the daemon line, you'll notice that the program does not finish, you'll have to interrupt it manually.
Setting the threads to daemon threads makes sure that they are killed once they have finished.

Note: you could achieve the same thing here without daemon threads, if you would replace the infinite while loop with another condition:

```py
def basic_worker(q):
        while not q.empty():
            item = q.get()
            # do_work(item)
            print(item)
            q.task_done()
```

Comment: Making `Thread`s daemonic does not make sure they are killed once they finish—it allows them to be killed whether they're finished or not. To make sure one's finished, you would need to call its [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method.