# How to stop a looping thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

What's the proper way to tell a looping thread to stop looping?

I have a fairly simple program that pings a specified host in a separate `threading.Thread` class. In this class it sleeps 60 seconds, the runs again until the application quits.

I'd like to implement a 'Stop' button in my `wx.Frame` to ask the looping thread to stop. It doesn't need to end the thread right away, it can just stop looping once it wakes up.

Here is my `threading` class (note: I haven't implemented looping yet, but it would likely fall under the run method in PingAssets)

```
class PingAssets(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadNum, asset, window):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadNum = threadNum
        self.window = window
        self.asset = asset

    def run(self):
        config = controller.getConfig()
        fmt = config['timefmt']
        start_time = datetime.now().strftime(fmt)
        try:
            if onlinecheck.check_status(self.asset):
                status = "online"
            else:
                status = "offline"
        except socket.gaierror:
            status = "an invalid asset tag."
        msg =("{}: {} is {}.   \n".format(start_time, self.asset, status))
        wx.CallAfter(self.window.Logger, msg)
```

And in my wxPyhton Frame I have this function called from a Start button:

```
def CheckAsset(self, asset):
        self.count += 1
        thread = PingAssets(self.count, asset, self)
        self.threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

## Threaded stoppable function

Instead of subclassing `threading.Thread`, one can modify the function to allow
stopping by a flag.

We need an object, accessible to running function, to which we set the flag to stop running.

We can use `threading.currentThread()` object.

```
import threading
import time


def doit(arg):
    t = threading.currentThread()
    while getattr(t, "do_run", True):
        print ("working on %s" % arg)
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Stopping as you wish.")


def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target=doit, args=("task",))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    t.do_run = False
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The trick is, that the running thread can have attached additional properties. The solution builds
on assumptions:

- the thread has a property "do_run" with default value `True`
- driving parent process can assign to started thread the property "do_run" to `False`.

Running the code, we get following output:

```
$ python stopthread.py                                                        
working on task
working on task
working on task
working on task
working on task
Stopping as you wish.
```

### Pill to kill - using Event

Other alternative is to use `threading.Event` as function argument. It is by
default `False`, but external process can "set it" (to `True`) and function can
learn about it using `wait(timeout)` function.

We can `wait` with zero timeout, but we can also use it as the sleeping timer (used below).

```
def doit(stop_event, arg):
    while not stop_event.wait(1):
        print ("working on %s" % arg)
    print("Stopping as you wish.")


def main():
    pill2kill = threading.Event()
    t = threading.Thread(target=doit, args=(pill2kill, "task"))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    pill2kill.set()
    t.join()
```

Edit: I tried this in Python 3.6. `stop_event.wait()` blocks the event (and so the while loop) until release. It does not return a boolean value. Using `stop_event.is_set()` works instead.

### Stopping multiple threads with one pill

Advantage of pill to kill is better seen, if we have to stop multiple threads
at once, as one pill will work for all.

The `doit` will not change at all, only the `main` handles the threads a bit differently.

```
def main():
    pill2kill = threading.Event()
    tasks = ["task ONE", "task TWO", "task THREE"]

    def thread_gen(pill2kill, tasks):
        for task in tasks:
            t = threading.Thread(target=doit, args=(pill2kill, task))
            yield t

    threads = list(thread_gen(pill2kill, tasks))
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    pill2kill.set()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Comment: There is an issue, Imagine we set a kernel signal like SIGALRM and in the handler of the signal we want to stop the process and threads using your method (pill2kill.set and then join) and then sys.exit(0).
1)If you run the application and wait for n seconds, it works fine
2)if you press ctrl+c, it works fine
3)but, if you press ctrl+z and then wait for some seconds and then "fg" to resume the process, if the n seconds of the SIGALRM has passed, the process will be stopped but the threads keep working for some milliseconds.
I have a piece of code to prove it, do you have any idea for that?

Comment: Pill to kill is what I was looking for as I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor and only have Futures instead of threads to set some attributes like `do_run`

Comment: Also, if you don't want to wait you can use [is_set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#threading.Event.is_set) instead of a `wait` with 0 timeout

Comment: `threading.currentThread` is a deprecated alias for `threading.current_thread`. https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/threading.html#threading.current_thread

Answer (score 29):

This has been asked before on Stack. See the following links:

- [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)
- [Stopping a thread after a certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524459/stopping-a-thread-python)

Basically you just need to set up the thread with a stop function that sets a sentinel value that the thread will check. In your case, you'll have the something in your loop check the sentinel value to see if it's changed and if it has, the loop can break and the thread can die.

Answer (score 14):

I read the other questions on Stack but I was still a little confused on communicating across classes. Here is how I approached it:

I use a list to hold all my threads in the `__init__` method of my wxFrame class: `self.threads = []`

As recommended in [How to stop a looping thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018033/how-to-stop-a-looping-thread-in-python) I use a signal in my thread class which is set to `True` when initializing the threading class.

```
class PingAssets(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadNum, asset, window):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadNum = threadNum
        self.window = window
        self.asset = asset
        self.signal = True

    def run(self):
        while self.signal:
             do_stuff()
             sleep()
```

and I can stop these threads by iterating over my threads:

```
def OnStop(self, e):
        for t in self.threads:
            t.signal = False
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a different approach. I've sub-classed a Thread class and in the constructor I've created an Event object. Then I've written custom join() method, which first sets this event and then calls a parent's version of itself.

Here is my class, I'm using for serial port communication in wxPython app:

```
import wx, threading, serial, Events, Queue

class PumpThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__ (self, port, queue, parent):
        super(PumpThread, self).__init__()
        self.port = port
        self.queue = queue
        self.parent = parent

        self.serial = serial.Serial()
        self.serial.port = self.port
        self.serial.timeout = 0.5
        self.serial.baudrate = 9600
        self.serial.parity = 'N'

        self.stopRequest = threading.Event()

    def run (self):
        try:
            self.serial.open()
        except Exception, ex:
            print ("[ERROR]\tUnable to open port {}".format(self.port))
            print ("[ERROR]\t{}\n\n{}".format(ex.message, ex.traceback))
            self.stopRequest.set()
        else:
            print ("[INFO]\tListening port {}".format(self.port))
            self.serial.write("FLOW?\r")

        while not self.stopRequest.isSet():
            msg = ''
            if not self.queue.empty():
                try:
                    command = self.queue.get()
                    self.serial.write(command)
                except Queue.Empty:
                    continue

            while self.serial.inWaiting():
                char = self.serial.read(1)
                if '\r' in char and len(msg) > 1:
                    char = ''
                    #~ print('[DATA]\t{}'.format(msg))
                    event = Events.PumpDataEvent(Events.SERIALRX, wx.ID_ANY, msg)
                    wx.PostEvent(self.parent, event)
                    msg = ''
                    break
                msg += char
        self.serial.close()

    def join (self, timeout=None):
        self.stopRequest.set()
        super(PumpThread, self).join(timeout)

    def SetPort (self, serial):
        self.serial = serial

    def Write (self, msg):
        if self.serial.is_open:
            self.queue.put(msg)
        else:
            print("[ERROR]\tPort {} is not open!".format(self.port))

    def Stop(self):
        if self.isAlive():
            self.join()
```

The Queue is used for sending messages to the port and main loop takes responses back. I've used no serial.readline() method, because of different end-line char, and I have found the usage of io classes to be too much fuss.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you run in that thread.
If that's your code, then you can implement a stop condition (see other answers).

However, if what you want is to run someone else's code, then you should fork and start a process. Like this:

```py
import multiprocessing
proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=your_proc_function, args=())
proc.start()
```

now, whenever you want to stop that process, send it a SIGTERM like this:

```py
proc.terminate()
proc.join()
```

And it's not slow: fractions of a second.
Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
import threading, time

def a():
    t = threading.currentThread()
    while getattr(t, "do_run", True):
    print('Do something')
    time.sleep(1)

def getThreadByName(name):
    threads = threading.enumerate() #Threads list
    for thread in threads:
        if thread.name == name:
            return thread

threading.Thread(target=a, name='228').start() #Init thread
t = getThreadByName('228') #Get thread by name
time.sleep(5)
t.do_run = False #Signal to stop thread
t.join()
```

Comment: Add # behind or below the code and explain what the line is for. Just dumping code keeps us "not smart" ;-) Tip: make your answer a working solution for others to paste in their interpreter. Adding additional code to do so is aloud. Welcome and enjoy SO. End of Review.

Comment: There's no need in converting Thread object to string and then parsing the string to get thread's name, when you can use its `name` property.

Naming is another issue of this code, for example, I don't get why `flex` is a reasonable name for threads list. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go) you can find more recipes on how to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to have a class, derived from `threading.Thread`, to encapsulate my thread functionality. You simply provide your own main loop in an overridden version of `run()` in this class. Calling `start()` arranges for the object’s `run()` method to be invoked in a separate thread.

Inside the main loop, periodically check whether a `threading.Event` has been set. Such an event is thread-safe.

Inside this class, you have your own `join()` method that sets the stop event object before calling the `join()` method of the base class. It can optionally take a time value to pass to the base class's `join()` method to ensure your thread is terminated in a short amount of time.

```
import threading
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, sleep_time=0.1):
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        self._sleep_time = sleep_time
        """call base class constructor"""
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        """main control loop"""
        while not self._stop_event.isSet():
            #do work
            print("hi")
            self._stop_event.wait(self._sleep_time)

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        """set stop event and join within a given time period"""
        self._stop_event.set()
        super().join(timeout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = MyThread()
    t.start()

    time.sleep(5)

    t.join(1) #wait 1s max
```

Having a small sleep inside the main loop before checking the `threading.Event` is less CPU intensive than looping continuously. You can have a default sleep time (e.g. 0.1s), but you can also pass the value in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't have control over the running target. In those cases you can use [`signal.pthread_kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.pthread_kill) to send a stop signal.

```py
from signal import pthread_kill, SIGTSTP
from threading import Thread
from itertools import count
from time import sleep

def target():
    for num in count():
        print(num)
        sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target=target)
thread.start()
sleep(5)
pthread_kill(thread.ident, SIGTSTP)
```

result

```bash
0
1
2
3
4

[14]+  Stopped
```