# Way to interrupt long calculations in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I have some object, that can perform operations that take a lot of time. I need some way to interrupt it after a some timeout.
My code looks like this:

```
def f(obj):
    time.sleep(600)
    obj.cancel()
t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(obj,))
t.start()
result = obj.ExecuteLongCommand(arguments)
t.stop() # Oops!
```

So, is there an *[easy]* way to perform `async` `cancelable` operation? My thread `t` is `async`, but is not `cancelable`.

Comment: Possible solition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018033/how-to-stop-a-looping-thread-in-python

Comment: are you in control of the implementation of ExecuteLongCommand?

Comment: No, it is third-party module

Comment: @qwetty, as I see, I need to define a new `stoppable` implementation for `Thread`. Seems working, but I surprised, that there is no `build-in` option.

Comment: @Jury because it's bad practice :) Thread could run other threads, allocate some resources and they should finished/released normally not by thread killing. Maybe it's worth to make some research and find way to accomplish the same thing but in different way.