# threads stopped using __stop are not removed from threading.enumerate()

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Basically, I have some threads that MAY block on I/O but has to be stopped in some cases. The entire software architecture is already designed like that, so switching to multi-processing can be painful. Therefore, I searched web and found using `thread_ref._Thread__stop()` seems to be the only way that can guarantee to stop a blocked thread.

The problem now is, though that thread is stopped, it is NOT removed from `threading.enumerate()`. If I call `isAlive()` on its reference, it returns `False`. I tried if a thread's `run()` method returns normally, that thread should be removed from that list.

This is bad, because if threading still has a reference to that `Thread` object, its resources will not be collected, theoretically, and may eventually cause memory leak.

What should I do to make sure things are cleaned up after I do `_Thread__stop` on a thread?

Comment: There is no supported way to stop a thread in Python.  In particular, the `_stop()` method does nothing of the sort, and was made private precisely because it's an implementation detail of no conceivable use outside of `Thread`'s internal bookkeeping (it does _not_ stop the thread - it's used by `Thread` internals when a thread exits on its own).  More here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018033/how-to-stop-a-looping-thread-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, nobody ever believes this ;-) , so here's some code that *shows* it (Python 2 only):

```
from time import sleep
import threading

def f():
    while True:
        print("running")
        sleep(1)

t = threading.Thread(target=f)
print("starting thread")
t.start()
sleep(.5)
print("'stopping' thread")
t._Thread__stop()
sleep(2)
print("huh! thread is still running")
sleep(10)
```

And the output:

```
starting thread
running
'stopping' thread
running
running
huh! thread is still running
running
running
running
running
running
running
running
running
running
running
```

`_Thread__stop` is useless for stopping the thread (there's nothing else in `threading` that can force a thread to stop either).

What calling it *does* do is put `threading`'s internals into a confused state.  In this case, because `._stop()` was called some other parts of `threading` erroneously *believe* the thread has stopped, so Python merrily exits after the final sleep despite that the non-daemon thread `t` is still running.

But that's not a bug:  you use private, undocumented methods (like `._stop()`) at your own risk.