# how to kill a python thread under certain conditions

Tags: python

I am trying to start a thread using python threading module. I want to kill this newly created thread under certain conditions. I have written below code snippet but this seems to hang and process never returns

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import os, signal
def sum():
    print("ada")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("ada1")

current = Thread(target=sum)
current.start()
current.join()
cur_pid = os.getpid()
print(cur_pid)
os.kill(cur_pid, signal.SIGSTOP)
print(current)
```

Comment: Do you want to kill the newly created process or the program itself?

Comment: @Max: I want to kill newly created process

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a looping thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018033/how-to-stop-a-looping-thread-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to send `SIGKILL` or `SIGTERM`, not `SIGSTOP`.

`SIGSTOP` pauses the process (which sounds like what you're seeing).

Comment: Problem is SIGKILL terminates the whole script. my last code line is never executed. I only want to kill this particular thread which is calling function

Comment: With os.getpid() he is getting the PID of the actual program that created the thread, he is stopping the program instead of the thread