# How to stop a thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am a beginner in Python.
I use to code with **Tkinter**. I want to improve my programs with the extension **"threading"**.
However, in some of my programs, if i leave the Tkinter window, the program is **still running**.
I would like to know **how stop it**. I guess it's the thread which is still running. I tried different ways to close the thread, but the only issue i found is to create an error (and it is not a nice solution according to me) :).

I would like to know if **an instruction** like the following one exist to stop the thread.

```
Thread(target=FinTemps).stop()
```

(I know that 'stop' is not working)

and if it is possible to stop the Thread **with a loop 'while'**, I tried this and i don't understand why it doesn't work :

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread as Th
from time import *

global end
end=False

begining=time()

def screen():
    global end
    while end==False:
        chrono=time()-beginning
        if chrono<5:
            sentence.set("Hey !")
        elif chrono<8:
            sentence.set("What's up ?")

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(fenêtre.winfo_screenwidth(), window.winfo_screenheight()))
window.title("Test Tkinter & Thread")

sentence=tk.StringVar()
sentence.set("none")
GreatTitle=tk.Label(window, textvariable=sentence, width=500)

Th(target=screen).start()

GreatTitle.pack(expand=1)

window.mainloop()

end=True
```

Thank you ;)
(And sorry if my english is not wonderful (I'm french) or if my code or explainations weren't very understandable or without following traditional presentation).

Have a good day :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a looping thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018033/how-to-stop-a-looping-thread-in-python)

Comment: @funie200: For what the OP requested, yeah, it's a duplicate. But this was definitely [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040), and the solution has nothing to do with stopping a thread, so I wouldn't consider it a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is not safe. `tkinter` is not thread-safe, and running *any* `tkinter` API cross-thread risks corruption of various kinds.

Bright side is, you don't need threads here. In real code, you wouldn't use a thread at all, you'd just schedule the changes to occur on `tkinter`'s event loop with [the `after` method](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method), simplifying your code to just:

```
import tkinter as tk

window=tk.Tk()
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(window.winfo_screenwidth(), window.winfo_screenheight()))
window.title("Test Tkinter & Thread")

sentence=tk.StringVar()
sentence.set("none")
GreatTitle=tk.Label(window, textvariable=sentence, width=500)

GreatTitle.pack(expand=1)

window.after(0, sentence.set, "Hey !")        # Happens almost immediately, as in thread case
window.after(5000, sentence.set, "What's up ?")  # Delays five seconds, as in thread case
window.mainloop()
```

This is also far more efficient than what you had; as written, your thread would spin *forever*, constantly looping without pause for as long as it was allowed to do so, keeping a core constantly running at 100%; the GUI itself would run slower because it couldn't do much of its work while the other thread held the GIL. Using `.after`, no meaningful resources are consumed at any time aside from the moment the event fires and the `sentence` is updated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your while loop checks `end` too frequent, it may cause race condition when you try to set `end` to True after the root window is destroyed.

You can try adding a short sleep inside the while loop to reduce the chance of race condition:

```py
while end == False:
    ...
    sleep(0.1)
```