# How can I make this code faster with multi threading

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make this code faster with multi threading

```py
import pyautogui
while True:
    pyautogui.typewrite("hello :)")
    pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping for some milliseconds during the while loop might stop it from slowing down your system.

```py
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

while True:
    pyautogui.typewrite("hello :)")
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    sleep(0.01)   # 10 ms
```

If you want to execute your code within a seperated thread you have to stop it at some point:
[How to stop a looping thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018033/ddg#36499538)
But then your code is getting complicated.