# How to kill this threading.Timer?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

I have launched a thread using a `Timer` object. Now, I want to stop this thread but I can't. I have used `cancel()`, but it doesn't work. I don't know why.

```
import threading
import time
import sys as system
def Nop():
    print("do nothing")
    return 0
def function():
    try:
        while True:
            print("hello world ")
            time.sleep(2)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print( "Good job!! exception catched") 
t = threading.Timer(10, function)
t.start()
print(t.getName)
counter = 0
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1) 
        Nop()
        counter = counter +1
        print(counter)
        if counter == 20:
            print(t.getName)
            t.cancel()
            counter = 0
            break
        if t.is_alive() == False:
            print("The Timer thread is dead...")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("End of program")
        t.cancel()
        system.exit(0)
    except:
        print("something wrong happens...")
if t.is_alive() == True:
    print("timer is alive...")
    print(t.getName)
    t.cancel()
print("final")
system.exit(0)
```

The thread should stop when counter is equal to 20, but it is still alive. When I am out of the while loop, there is another check. The Timer is alive, is the same thread, I try to cancel, but it doesn't work.

Any Idea?

```
do nothing
17
hello world 
do nothing
18
do nothing
19
hello world do nothing

20
<bound method _Timer.getName of <_Timer(Thread-6, started daemon 9916)>>
timer is alive...
<bound method _Timer.getName of <_Timer(Thread-6, started daemon 9916)>>
final
To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 0

hello world 
hello world 
hello world 
hello world
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem here can be solved by reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) more carefully. A timer thread's `cancel` method "... will only work if the timer is still in its waiting stage."

By the time you call `t.cancel` the timer has fired, and its associated function is executing so it is no longer "in its waiting stage", even though the function actually spends most of its time sleeping - this does NOT mean it's in its waiting stage, which terminates when the timer fires..

More generally there is no way to kill a thread without its active cooperation, as [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524459/stopping-a-thread-after-a-certain-amount-of-time) already summarize well.

Rather than using `cancel` you should set some sort of flag that `function` looks at to determine whether it should terminate its loop (and therefore the whole thread) or not.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right. I set a flag in function to stop the loop and now works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
del threadTimer
```

I don't this will work or not, but the `cancel` method should be used on the waiting stage. See the documentation for more help. You are trying to use cancel the timer after it's waiting stage.
If the `del` statement doesn't work, try this:

```
threadTimer = None
```

Hopefully some of this helps.