# how to cancel timer when timer not in wait stage

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

[python thread doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

According to docs about python, the Timer.cancel() will only work if the timer is still in its waiting stage, but we cann't get the timer stage, how can I sure the timer will be shutdown after I execute Timer.cancel() whenever.

thanks.

Comment: May be you want to have a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565773/how-to-kill-this-threading-timer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill this threading.Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565773/how-to-kill-this-threading-timer)