# Timeout function using threading in python does not work

Tags: python, timeout

I have found a code creating a timeout function [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473878-timeout-function-using-threading/), which does not seem to work. The complete test code is below:

```
def timeout(func, args=(), kwargs={}, timeout_duration=1, default=None):
    import threading
    class InterruptableThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.result = None

        def run(self):
            try:
                self.result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                self.result = default

    it = InterruptableThread()
    it.start()
    it.join(timeout_duration)
    if it.isAlive():
        return default
    else:
        return it.result


def foo():
    while True:
        pass

timeout(foo,timeout_duration=3)
```

Expected behavior: code ends within 3 seconds. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A thread can not gracefully kill another thread, so with your current code, `foo` never terminates. (With `thread.daemon = True` the Python program will exit when only daemon threads are left, but that does not allow you to terminate `foo` without also terminating the main thread.)

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/q/366682/190597) have tried to use signals to halt execution, but this may be [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1114567/190597) in some cases.

If you can modify `foo`, there are many solutions possible. For instance, you could check for a `threading.Event` to break out of the while-loop.

But if you can not modify `foo`, you could run it in a subprocess using the `multiprocessing` module since unlike threads, subprocesses can be terminated. Here is an example of how that might look:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(x = 1):
    cnt = 1
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(x, cnt)
        cnt += 1

def timeout(func, args = (), kwds = {}, timeout = 1, default = None):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 1)
    result = pool.apply_async(func, args = args, kwds = kwds)
    try:
        val = result.get(timeout = timeout)
    except mp.TimeoutError:
        pool.terminate()
        return default
    else:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeout(foo, kwds = {'x': 'Hi'}, timeout = 3, default = 'Bye'))
    print(timeout(foo, args = (2,), timeout = 2, default = 'Sayonara'))
```

yields

```
('Hi', 1)
('Hi', 2)
('Hi', 3)
Bye
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
Sayonara
```

Note that this has some limitations too.

- subprocesses receive a *copy* of the parent processes' variables. If you modify a variable in a subprocess, it will *NOT* affect
  the parent process. If your function `func` needs to modify variables, you will need to use a [shared variable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).
- arguments (passed through `args`) and keywords (`kwds`) must be
  picklable.
- processes are more resource-heavy than threads. Usually, you only
  want to create a multiprocessing Pool once at the beginning of a
  program. This `timeout` function creates a `Pool` every time you call it. This was necessary since we needed `pool.terminate()` to
  terminate `foo`. There might be a better way, but I haven't thought of it.

Comment: Thanks, it works well for me. However, because of the returns it seems `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` are never called.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn `it` into a [daemon thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation):

```
it = ...
it.daemon = True
it.start()
```

Otherwise it's created as a user thread, and the process won't get stopped until all the user threads have finished.

Note that with your implementation the thread will continue to run and consume resources even after you've timed out waiting for it. CPython's [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) could exacerbate the issue further.

Comment: Oh so maybe this code it not what I am looking for. I am looking for a function `timeout` that uses a different function `foo` (API as in the code above), that returns the result of `foo` as soon `foo` has ended, or a default value otherwise (as in the example). In both cases, I do not want to have something run, Maybe the use of `signal` is better? I have no idea what the Global Interpreter Lock is, but it is way too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The benefit of using `multiprocessing` is the processes do not share memory and whatever happens in the child remains limited to that function and will not cause other process to terminate. The easiest way to add a timeout of 3s to a child process is:

```
import multiprocessing

def my_child():
    function here

process = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_child)
process.daemon = True
process.start()

process.join(3)
if process.is_alive():
    process.terminate()
```