# Python , Timeout on a function on child thread without using signal and thread.join

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I want to add a timeout on one function which is getting called inside a child thread.
I can't use a signal, as a signal should be on the main thread.
I can't use `thread.join(time_out)`, as that function can sometimes be executed in a few seconds, and in those cases the thread will always wait out the `time_out`.

Are there any other approaches?

Sources:

- `thread.join`: [Timeout function using threading in python does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821156/timeout-function-using-threading-in-python-does-not-work)
- `signal`: [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish)

Comment: I Think threading has a Timer class.. can you use that?

Comment: timer class is to start a thread after certain time.here ,i want to stop the execution of thread after certain time.

Comment: usually I poll - taking the current time and doing a while. Have a look at the function in line 10. https://github.com/niccokunzmann/pynet/blob/master/process/test_multi_Process.py

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little known `ctyps` hack to raise a `TimeoutError` targeting a specific thread. I made a `non_blocking` timeout script using this method and just released it on GitHub: https://github.com/levimluke/PyTimeoutAfter

It's SUPER simple to implement, but technically complex.

```
    def raise_caller(self):
        ret = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(ctypes.c_long(self._caller_thread._ident), ctypes.py_object(self._exception))
        if ret == 0:
            raise ValueError("Invalid thread ID")
        elif ret > 1:
            ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(self._caller_thread._ident, NULL)
            raise SystemError("PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc failed")
```

https://github.com/levimluke/PyTimeoutAfter/blob/main/timeout_after.py#L47

I use a class object and save the calling thread to, that way I can raise an exception in the parent class from within the timed child thread.