# Python multiprocessing: Will child process hang if the parent process was killed?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery, child-process

I need help to clarify some concepts. Right now I'm using celery(a python scheduler) to run a task. Since celery has time limit for a task(300s should be default) and my task is very likely to run longer, I decided to spawn a process inside that task to do the actual work. However, what I don't know is that if during the execution of the task, I accidentally restart/stop celery server, will the process that spawned still working? Or it will become a zombie process? Please give me some details if possible. Thanks!

Edit: One more question: when you do

```
p = Process(target=f, args=('test',))
p.start()
```

Does p become a child process for current process? Or it just create an independent process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I can only answer your first question, not being very familiar with Celery, perhaps you can find the answer in the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html).

Your question highlights the distinction between daemon and non-daemon threads.

**Daemon** threads are those which will not hang up the main program.  They will keep working until they finish, regardless of what the main program is doing.

**Non-Daemon** threads are just the opposite.  They must be killed before the main program ends.

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation) does a good job of explaining the difference and implications.

In the scope of your question, if your processes are daemon threads, they should be fine if you restart/stop your server. However, if they aren't daemon threads, you shouldn't be able to stop the celery server (assuming my understanding of daemon threads is correct)

Hopefully this helps