# How to force main thread to close if a sub thread is alive in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

How to force main thread to close if a sub thread is alive in python?

`sys.exit()` and `exit()` appears to wait for sub thread to complete?

Comment: Might be because the sub-threads are set as non-daemon threads. Not sure if this would block the execution from stopping however. Might be worth looking into. If you're using the Threading module there's an option in initialization to determine its daemon status. By default all Threading processes inherit their parent thread status. Since the parent is main they will be set to non-daemon. To change this you would set it to daemon=False during initialization.

Comment: To quote one of the answers: "Without daemon threads, you'd have to keep track of them, and tell them to exit, before your program can completely quit."

Comment: I see... well the idea was to kill the main thread in order to kill the sub threads... will this be anyway possible in python?

Comment: @user3388884 If you want the sub threads to die when the main thread dies, make your sub threads daemon threads: `subthread.daemon = True`. You have to set them as daemon before you call `start()` on them.

Comment: You should look at this other post on SO [Is there a way to kill a Thread in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python). You will find all the elements for your question.

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions... I might find my solution under that link... @RobWatts to my understanding, when daemon threads will not die if main thread dies right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your sub threads into daemon threads. For example:

```
class SubThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True # Makes the thread a daemon thread
        ...
```

Or

```
subThread = threading.Thread(...)
subThread.daemon = True
```

When your program ends, *all daemon threads will immediately die*. If the sub threads are not daemon threads, then they *must* be stopped before your program will end. As Serge mentioned in a comment, "[Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)" talks about ways to stop threads.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into setting it as a daemon thread.  See information about daemon threads at [Daemon Threads Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation).  Then it shouldn't wait for that thread to complete.

Comment: thanks so much everyone... I completely misunderstood characteristics of daemon threads.

Comment: But what function do I use to actually exit the main program? I'm using sys.exit(), but it doesn't seem to exit the main thread even when sub thread are set to Daemon...