# Why are daemons called daemons?

Tags: unix, daemon

It has been itching me for a long time to know what the historical reason for calling daemon programs or threads *"daemon"*

> **Lat: daemon**, latin version of the Greek "δαίμων" ("godlike power, fate, god")
>
> - **god**,
> - a subordinate **deity**, as the genius of a place or a person's attendant spirit

There are numerous questions clarifying what [daemons are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java) and [how they behave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation), but none explaining the origins of the term *"daemon"* for programs that run in the background like `sshd`.

Why do we title programs that run in the background as daemons?

Comment: You can find some answers [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31430/what-is-the-origin-of-daemon-with-regards-to-computing).

Comment: I was wondering, too.  And it's nice that we can get some levity thrown in with all these "why won't this work" questions.  :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29#Etymology)

> According to Fernando J. Corbato who worked on Project MAC in 1963 his
>   team is the first to use the term daemon. The use of the term daemon
>   was inspired by Maxwell's daemon, in physics and thermodynamics as an
>   imaginary agent which helped to sort molecules.
>
> "We fancifully began to use the word daemon to describe background
>   processes which worked tirelessly to perform system chores."
>
> In the Unix System Administration Handbook, Evi Nemeth states the
>   following about daemons:
>
> "Many people equate the word "daemon" with the word "demon", implying
>   some kind of satanic connection between UNIX and the underworld. This
>   is an egregious misunderstanding. "Daemon" is actually a much older
>   form of "demon"; daemons have no particular bias towards good or evil,
>   but rather serve to help define a person's character or personality.
>   The ancient Greeks' concept of a "personal daemon" was similar to the
>   modern concept of a "guardian angel"—eudaemonia is the state of being
>   helped or protected by a kindly spirit. As a rule, UNIX systems seem
>   to be infested with both daemons and demons."

Answer (score 8):

According to Wikipedia:

The term was coined by the programmers of MIT's Project MAC. They took the name from Maxwell's demon, an imaginary being from a thought experiment that constantly works in the background, sorting molecules.

Unix systems inherited this terminology. Maxwell's Demon is consistent with Greek mythology's interpretation of a daemon as a supernatural being working in the background, with no particular bias towards good or evil. However, BSD and some of its derivatives have adopted a Christian demon as their mascot rather than a Greek daemon.

More [here](http://ei.cs.vt.edu/~history/Daemon.html).

And [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31430/what-is-the-origin-of-daemon-with-regards-to-computing).

And [here](http://bfy.tw/2ltb).