# daemon thread doesn't stop in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Why doesn't the main thread kill the daemon one?

```
import threading
import time

print_lock = threading.Lock()

def exampleNoneDaemon():
    for x in range(3):
        with print_lock:
            print(x, "master")
        time.sleep(0.7)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=exampleNoneDaemon)
t1.start()

def exampleDaemon():
    while True:
        with print_lock:
            print("daemon")
        time.sleep(1)

t2 = threading.Thread(target=exampleDaemon)
t2.daemon = True
t2.start()
```

the output of this code is:

```
0 master
daemon
1 master
daemon
2 master
daemon
daemon
daemon
daemon
...
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Your code works for me. What OS and Python version are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 python 3.5, I dont get it why the daemon function doesnt stop for me

Comment: How are you running this code?