# How do I stop the threads once I found my target?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I wrote a python that will find what the pin the users inputs, everything works fine except one thing, and that's that the script won't exist once the pin is found. Is there a why I can kill all of the other threads once I found the pin?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
#
#
#
from threading import Thread
from random import randint 
from time import sleep 
from sys import exit
from os import system

system('clear');sleep(0.7)
Pin = int(raw_input('Enter a pin: '))


def Up():
    global Pin
    for pin in xrange(1111,10000):
        system('clear')
        print pin
        if pin == Pin:
            system('clear')
            print 'U Pin Found: %d'%pin;sleep(0.7)
            for i in range(3):
                exit()


def Down():
    global Pin
    pins = xrange(10000)
    for pin in reversed(pins):
        system('clear')
        print pin
        if pin == Pin:
            system('clear')
            print 'D Pin Found: %d'%pin;sleep(0.7)
            exit()



def Random():
    global Pin

    while True:
        pins = randint(1111,10000)
        print pins
        if pins == Pin:
           system('clear')
           print 'R Pin Found: %d'%pins;sleep(0.7)
           exit()


Task1 = Thread(target=Up,args=())
Task2 = Thread(target=Down,args=())
Task3 = Thread(target=Random,args=())


Task1.start()
Task2.start()
Task3.start()
```

Comment: Off-topic: The way you're clearing the screen isn't very portable. Instead of `os.system('clear')` consider using `os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')`, which works on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @martineau And I wouldn't do it at all. I don't see the point in doing so.

Comment: @glglgl: My comment wasn't addressed to you. The point is _portability_. It would allow folks on other operating systems to easily run the code (and maybe provide a good answer the question).

Comment: @martineau Even if a comment isn't addressed at me, I felt free to comment on this topic as well. After all, it is a system where everyone can add comments at their will. You are completely right concerning portability: if one really needs clearing the screen, it is better to do it portably. But I personally feel programs which clear the screen over and over again just annoying, what I tried to express with this. (And I personally would prefer `subprocess` over `os.system()`, but that's another point.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply terminate them. However you can ask to stop. Please see example:

```
from threading import Thread
from random import randint 
from time import sleep 
from sys import exit
from os import system

system('clear');sleep(0.7)
Pin = int(raw_input('Enter a pin: '))

terminateAll = false

def Up():
    global Pin
    for pin in xrange(1111,10000):
        if terminateAll:
            exit()
        system('clear')
        print pin
        if pin == Pin:
            terminateAll = true
            system('clear')
            print 'U Pin Found: %d'%pin;sleep(0.7)
            for i in range(3):
                exit()


def Down():
    global Pin
    pins = xrange(10000)
    for pin in reversed(pins):
        if terminateAll:
            exit()
        system('clear')
        print pin
        if pin == Pin:
            terminateAll = true
            system('clear')
            print 'D Pin Found: %d'%pin;sleep(0.7)
            exit()



def Random():
    global Pin

    while True:
        if terminateAll:
            exit()
        pins = randint(1111,10000)
        print pins
        if pins == Pin:
           terminateAll = true
           system('clear')
           print 'R Pin Found: %d'%pins;sleep(0.7)
           exit()


Task1 = Thread(target=Up,args=())
Task2 = Thread(target=Down,args=())
Task3 = Thread(target=Random,args=())


Task1.start()
Task2.start()
Task3.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make the thread objects [daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation) by setting their [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) to attribute to `True` *before* starting them.

The default value is `False`. Any daemon threads still running when the main program thread ends will automatically be terminated.

A logical place to do this is right after calling their constructor:

```
  ...
Task1 = Thread(target=Up,args=())
Task1.daemon = True
Task2 = Thread(target=Down,args=())
Task2.daemon = True
Task3 = Thread(target=Random,args=())
Task3.daemon = True

Task1.start()
Task2.start()
Task3.start()
```