# How to wait until all threads finished?

Tags: python, multithreading, download

Though I googled and got a lot of result, but they are not what I want. My main code as below

```
def main:
    start = datetime.now()
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    download()
    browser.quit()
    showTime()

def download:
    for imageSecond in imageSeconds:
        urlServer = imageSecond.get("src")
        pathLocal = formatPath(downloadLocationPath, ntpath.basename(urlServer))

        if not os.path.isfile(pathLocal):
             ts.append(createNewDownloadThread(browser, urlServer, pathLocal))
        else:
            logger.info('Downloaded: {}'.format(urlServer + " -> " + pathLocal))
            showTime()

    for t in ts:
        t.join()

def showTime:
    end = datetime.now()
    runtime = end - start
    logger.info('Sta Time: {}'.format(start))
    logger.info('End Time: {}'.format(end))
    logger.info('Run Time: {}'.format(runtime))
    sys.exit(0)
```

I got output as below

```
2017-02-27 09:42:12,817 - INFO - MainThread - Downloaded: https://secure-api.userlocal.jp
2017-02-27 09:42:12,833 - INFO - MainThread - Sta Time: 2017-02-27 09:41:43.895126
2017-02-27 09:42:12,833 - INFO - MainThread - End Time: 2017-02-27 09:42:12.833492
2017-02-27 09:42:12,833 - INFO - MainThread - Run Time: 0:00:28.938366
2017-02-27 09:42:12,849 - INFO - Thread-323 - Download: https://secure-api.userlocal.jp
2017-02-27 09:42:12,849 - INFO - Thread-324 - Download: https://secure-api.userlocal.jp
```

But what I want to output as below, what can I do?

```
2017-02-27 09:42:12,817 - INFO - MainThread - Downloaded: https://secure-api.userlocal.jp
2017-02-27 09:42:12,849 - INFO - Thread-323 - Download: https://secure-api.userlocal.jp
2017-02-27 09:42:12,849 - INFO - Thread-324 - Download: https://secure-api.userlocal.jp
2017-02-27 09:42:12,833 - INFO - MainThread - Sta Time: 2017-02-27 09:41:43.895126
2017-02-27 09:42:12,833 - INFO - MainThread - End Time: 2017-02-27 09:42:12.833492
2017-02-27 09:42:12,833 - INFO - MainThread - Run Time: 0:00:28.938366
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is missing code in your sample, I guess you are calling newthread.start() in your createNewDownloadThread() method above, aren't you?

You might know the usual way of working is by calling thread.start() and thread.join(), so it will block until the thread has finished.

I'd say it might work better by doing this in your for loop:

```
   for t in ts:
      t.start()
      t.join()
```

Comment: I start it  in createNewDownloadThread, your code is not what I need because threads no in parallel. Then I found a strange result, the result above was used with PhantomJS, if I use ChromeDriver, the result is what I need, I am not sure why...

Comment: Ah!, probably because PhantomJS is single threaded and it's not working properly in your multithreading code.

Comment: Really? I aslo found PhantomJS is very slow on Mac, So PhantomJS is not good for my case? May I have to use ChromeDriver?

Comment: I'm thinking another problem you might have is the fact that you are starting the thread in a different context, as you are starting it into another function, but joining it in the caller one. Could you try to start() the thread after .append to your list? You could try also using .setDaemon(True) before the .append() and .start(), and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: I start() after append but same result. But setDaemon(True) show what I need! Can you explain for me about setDaemon(True)?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading

Comment: @mikezang you have a good explanation of .setDaemon(True) -now .daemon(True)- in this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation.