# kivy app doesn't access internet on mobile

Tags: android, permissions, kivy, buildozer

i started just recently with kivy. so far i have made 2 very simple apps working as expected on android. so now i tried to make more use of a mobile app using actual URLRequests.

on linux/pycharm the app itself works fine. afterwards i am building with buildozer. i start the app on the phone, hit the button, but nothing happens. i tried with different commands if the button itself is working and it does. but all command after the urlrequest are ignored. but the app is not crashing. basically just doing nothing.

i set the permission in buidlozer.spec to INTERNET.
also i tried to use logcat. but as soon i run logcat there are running dozens of lines continuously. even without even doing anything inside the app. so i can't find any useful information there.

are there some settings i would have to set inside my phone first? also how i can i debug efficient and get logcat to show juts the relevant lines?

thanks in advance for any help.

below are the a stripped down version of the app and the buildozer.spec

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest


class SynonymApp(App):  # Changed to a BoxLayout for simplicity
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (10, 0.4, 0, 1)

        self.label_list = []
        self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=30, size_hint=(1, None))
        self.app_label = Label(text='Synonym', font_size=30, height=100)
        self.usr_input = TextInput(height=40,
                                   font_size=20,
                                   size_hint_y=None,
                                   pos_hint={'top': 0.9})

        self.btn = Button(text='search ', size_hint_y=None,  pos_hint={'top': 0.8})
        for i in [self.app_label, self.usr_input, self.btn]: self.layout.add_widget(i)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(450, 350), pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}, do_scroll_x=False)
        root.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.layout.bind(minimum_height=self.layout.setter('height'))
        self.btn.bind(on_release=self.btn_down)
        return root

    def btn_down(self, value):
        request = self.do_url_request(self.usr_input.text)
        #check is anything happens afterwards
        self.btn.background_color = (10, 5, 1, 1)

    def do_url_request(self, term):
        url = r"https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/search?q={}&format=application/json" .format(term)
        request = UrlRequest(url)
        #for dev
        request.wait()
        return request


if __name__ == "__main__":
    SynonymApp().run()
```

buidozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Synonym

# (str) Package name
package.name = synonym

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = k13.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png



# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 1

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

**edit**
and here is the log

```
D/dalvikvm(22342): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420b89b8
D/dalvikvm(22342): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420b89b8
D/dalvikvm(22342): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420b89b8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22342): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420b89b8
D/dalvikvm(22342): Added shared lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420b89b8
D/dalvikvm(22342): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420b89b8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22342): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420b89b8
D/dalvikvm(22342): Added shared lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420b89b8
D/dalvikvm(22342): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420b89b8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22342): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so 0x420b89b8
E/dalvikvm(22342): dlopen("/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so" not found
D/dalvikvm(22342): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so 0x420b89b8
E/dalvikvm(22342): dlopen("/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found
I/python  (22342): Starting audio thread
I/python  (22342): Initialize Python for Android
I/python  (22342): ['/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/site-python']
I/python  (22342): Android path ['/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/_applibs']
I/python  (22342): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
I/python  (22342): Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
I/python  (22342): [WARNING           ] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 14)
I/python  (22342): [WARNING           ] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-04-24_0.txt
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Apr 24 2017, 23:43:46) 
I/python  (22342): [GCC 4.8]
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
I/python  (22342):  /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
I/python  (22342):  (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@45.0 AU@04.04.02.007.051 SKARAJGA_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.051+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.051__release_ENGG (CL@)>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 305>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Shader      ] program: <--From Vertex Shader:
I/python  (22342): --From Fragment Shader:
I/python  (22342): Link was successful.>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] found 17 joystick
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <0>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] discard joystick <0> cause no button
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <1>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <2>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <3>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <4>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <5>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <6>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <7>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <8>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <9>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <10>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <11>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <12>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <13>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <14>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <15>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <16>
I/python  (22342): [INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
I/python  (22342): Python for android ended.
I/ActivityManager(  867): Process k13.test.synonymi:python (pid 22342) (adj 0) has died.
E/dalvikvm(22539): >>>>> k13.test.synonymi:python [ userId:0 | appId:10233 ]
V/python  (22539): metadata fullscreen is1
D/dalvikvm(22539): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420aee78
D/dalvikvm(22539): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420aee78
D/dalvikvm(22539): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420aee78, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22539): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420aee78
D/dalvikvm(22539): Added shared lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420aee78
D/dalvikvm(22539): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420aee78, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22539): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420aee78
D/dalvikvm(22539): Added shared lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420aee78
D/dalvikvm(22539): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420aee78, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22539): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so 0x420aee78
E/dalvikvm(22539): dlopen("/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so" not found
D/dalvikvm(22539): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so 0x420aee78
E/dalvikvm(22539): dlopen("/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found
I/python  (22539): Starting audio thread
I/python  (22539): presplash-fit is null
I/python  (22539): presplash (fit=null) mx=0.527344,my=0.937500
I/python  (22539): Initialize Python for Android
I/python  (22539): ['/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/site-python']
I/python  (22539): Android path ['/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/_applibs']
I/python  (22539): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
I/python  (22539): Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-04-24_1.txt
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Apr 24 2017, 23:43:46) 
I/python  (22539): [GCC 4.8]
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
I/python  (22539):  /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
I/python  (22539):  (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@45.0 AU@04.04.02.007.051 SKARAJGA_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.051+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.051__release_ENGG (CL@)>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 305>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] found 17 joystick
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <0>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] discard joystick <0> cause no button
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <1>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <2>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <3>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <4>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <5>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <6>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <7>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <8>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <9>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <10>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <11>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <12>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <13>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <14>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <15>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <16>
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] Must go into sleep mode, check the app
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Android     ] App doesn't support pause mode, stop.
I/python  (22539): [INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
I/python  (22539): Python for android ended.
I/ActivityManager(  867): Process k13.test.synonymi:python (pid 22539) (adj 0) has died.
E/dalvikvm(22773): >>>>> k13.test.synonymi:python [ userId:0 | appId:10233 ]
V/python  (22773): metadata fullscreen is1
D/dalvikvm(22773): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420afe48
D/dalvikvm(22773): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420afe48
D/dalvikvm(22773): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/k13.test.synonymi-1/libpython2.7.so 0x420afe48, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22773): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420afe48
D/dalvikvm(22773): Added shared lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420afe48
D/dalvikvm(22773): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so 0x420afe48, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22773): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420afe48
D/dalvikvm(22773): Added shared lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420afe48
D/dalvikvm(22773): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so 0x420afe48, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(22773): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so 0x420afe48
E/dalvikvm(22773): dlopen("/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so" not found
D/dalvikvm(22773): Trying to load lib /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so 0x420afe48
E/dalvikvm(22773): dlopen("/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so" not found
I/python  (22773): Starting audio thread
I/python  (22773): presplash-fit is null
I/python  (22773): presplash (fit=null) mx=0.527344,my=0.937500
I/python  (22773): Initialize Python for Android
I/python  (22773): ['/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/site-python']
I/python  (22773): Android path ['/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files', '/data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/_applibs']
I/python  (22773): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
I/python  (22773): Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-04-24_2.txt
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Apr 24 2017, 23:43:46) 
I/python  (22773): [GCC 4.8]
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
I/python  (22773):  /data/data/k13.test.synonymi/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
I/python  (22773):  (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@45.0 AU@04.04.02.007.051 SKARAJGA_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.051+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.02.007.051__release_ENGG (CL@)>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 305>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] found 17 joystick
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <0>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] discard joystick <0> cause no button
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <1>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <2>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <3>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <4>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <5>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <6>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <7>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <8>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <9>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <10>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <11>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <12>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <13>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <14>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <15>
I/python  (22773): [INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <16>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter logcat results to only show python activity, use
`logcat -s python`. Also as the [document](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html#module-kivy.network.urlrequest) specifies, `UrlRequest` makes requests asynchronously (in a [daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation) thread) so even if something unexpected happens, the main thread won't crush, so look for the possible exceptions in the started daemon thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read the button status first in a if expression then call url.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).