# Why I can't get the output of "I get the source"

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to build a server to handle long time task job, so I made a global variable `tasks` so that request can easily returned by only put task info into `tasks`, and I using threading to build a function to handle the long time task job.
however I can't receive the `tasks` change in `test()`, why had this happen?

```
import time
import threading
from collections import OrderedDict

tasks = OrderedDict()


def request():
    # network gross
    # ...
    global tasks
    tasks['zdx'] = 2


def test():
    print('test runing')
    while True:
        if tasks:
            task = tasks.popitem()
            print('I get the source!')
            # very long time resolve task
        time.sleep(1)


def init():
    threading.Thread(target=test, daemon=True).start()


init()
time.sleep(3)
request()
```

Comment: Try putting a `time.sleep(3)` after `request()`, as the program terminated before the daemonised thread has a chance to respond to the task.

Comment: You need to pass `tasks` as an argument to `test`, otherwise `tasks` (inside of `test`) keeps the value it had when `test` was defined.

Comment: @HenryWoody nope, `tasks` can be accessed from `test()` as is because it didn't define a local `tasks` variable and it already exists on the global scope.

Comment: @metatoaster yeah you're right, I've forgotten the wild rules of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to review what [daemon=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190010/daemon-threads-explanation?noredirect=1&lq=1) does for a thread. Effectively, right as you called `request()` to put an entry into `tasks`, your program exits and the thread gets terminated (as it has `daemon=True` set) before it finished sleeping and never got a chance to find out if anything is in `tasks`, thus it never got a chance to run.  To correct for this, putting in a `time.sleep(3)` after `request()` at the end will ensure more than enough time for the loop in the thread to finish sleeping and process the check.